# simR power simulation for multiple fixed effects

Tags: r, simulation, mixed-models

I want to estimate my required study sample size based on simulation using pilot data. My model looks like this:

```
model1 <- glmer(decision ~ 1 + default + aest + obstruc + privatt + (1 + default + aest + obstruc | id), family = 'binomial', data = pilot_data)
```

The simR package offers the possibility of extending a given dataset and then calculate the power of your model at different stages of the number which was increased (in my case number of participants), visualized in a powercurve. Instead of testing only one fixed effect (via the `fixed` function) I would like to run `powerCurve` on my three main effects  simultanously (main effects are: default, aest and obstruc; privatt is a control variable). 
My idea is to use the `fcompare` function and compare my full model against a null model (with only the intercept).

My question is: Is this procedure statistically correct? In the end I want to check where my powercurve reaches 80% and recruit the according number of participants.

The code to extend the data set and produce the powercurve looks as follows:

```
model1_ext <- extend(model1, along='id', n='250')
pc_model1 <- powerCurve(model1_ext, fcompare(~ 1, method = 'pb'), along='id', nsim=1000 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're going to underestimate your required sample size.

The test you're proposing asks "are all of these effects, taken together, significant?". But if you want to know if a *specific* effect is significant, you're asking a little more from your data and so you'll probably need a larger sample size.

Your sample size will usually be determined by your "hardest" question, so I would recommend running a separate power curve for each effect.

---

If you're having trouble with the simulation time, it's probably okay to use `'kr'` rather than `'pb'`. The analysis is already an approximation (since we never know the 'true' values of the parameters we use for our simulations). If you're worried the two tests might give different results, you could double check your proposed sample size with `'pb'` in a single run of `powerSim`.